# Cannot access object properties via props in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, undefined, react-props

I fetch data from API and pass it to Table component like this:

```
function MainSectionOrganization() {

    const [obj, setObj] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/getCompanies')
        .then((response) => {
            return response.json();
        }).then((data) => {
            setObj(data);
        })
    }, []);

    return (
        <Table data={obj} />
    )
}
```

Then, in Table component, I try to do console.log for props.data[0] and I see data in Chrome terminal correctly.

```
import React from 'react';
import './Table.css';
import { useTable } from 'react-table';

function Table(props) {

    console.log(props.data[0]);
    ...
```

[image]

However, when I try to access any properties of the object, for example *console.log(props.data[0].OU01_Code*), I encounter an error ***Cannot read property '...' of undefined***

I see many people have solution with class component, but for some reason I need to use function component. Can you help me on this one ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hey the problem is that you trying to access `props.data[0].OU01_Code` and it is not there YET, so you need to make some kind of condition to check that it is there.
Try:

```js
if (props.data && props.data[0]) {
  console.log(props.data[0].OU01_Code)
}
```

Let me know if it helps, cheers

Comment: Your solution is working for me. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 4):

`fetch` is asynchronous.  So the *first* thing the component does is get rendered with an empty array:

```
const [obj, setObj] = useState([]);
//...
return (
    <Table data={obj} />
)
```

When that happens, any reference to an element of that array would be `undefined`:

```
props.data[0]
```

So trying to read a property of that undefined array element would result in that exact error:

```
props.data[0].OU01_Code
// Cannot read property 'OU01_Code' of undefined
```

*After* `fetch` resolves its result and the state is updated, `obj` has elements (presumably) and you can access them.

---

Conceptually, you need to handle the situation where your array is empty.  Do you want to display `<Table />` at all in that case?  If not, you can conditionally display it in the parent component:

```
return (
    <>
        {obj.length > 0 && <Table data={obj} />}
    </>
)
```

Or if you do want to display `<Table />` with an empty array then you'll need to include logic within that component (which we can't see at this time) to handle an empty array.  Basically, you need to check `props.data.length` before trying to access `props.data[0]`.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your suggestion. It is useful and it solves my problem.

Answer (score 1):

because the initial render will occur before the API call is completed you can use `props.data && console.log(props.data[0])` or if you're open to use **Optional chaining** it would be easy even `props?.data?.[0]`

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion.